# How do I compile specific sourcecode files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, console-application, project

So in VS, I create a project, right? Let's say I'm following a tutorial that has extra code that I don't need that only serves to show examples for looping, threads, etc. - then moves onto the real code. I take notes of everything so I usually save a copy of my source code with a different name as future notes. Now the only thing with projects in VS or any other C# compiler is that if you save the file AS "..." or make a new file, sometimes I find that the compiler will now compile the new code or the old code (it gets me so mixed up).

I get why it does this though, to link to other sourcefiles right? Well anyway, all I want to know is how do I compile a different C# file within my project folder? I don't want to create a new project, it just makes it harder for me to organize.

Comment: Nevermind. I guess I'll just make a new project everysingle time I want to save any old code instead. I'm tired of everything being so complicated.

Comment: My computer has low specs, 4GB of ram and 2.10 GHz dual-core processor. It takes a lot of productive time just to make a new project.As visual studio has to take time setting up the default template. It's also a pain to compile it from the command prompt too, I only have that set up on my school computer and toatally forgot the entire set-up process anyway.

Comment: [VS 2010 Express](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/5/1E5F1C0A-0D5B-426A-A603-1798B951DDAE/VS2010Express1.iso) is far more light weight.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to include a lot of files into project bu only compile one you can just change "Build action" to "none" from "compile" for CS files you don't want to build.

Comment: Thank you Alexei. But where do I find that on Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right click the file, Properties, you'll see the Build Option